# CKEditor is duplicating a field

Tags: ckeditor

So my original problem was that I needed to get rid of the img style attribute on images in CKeditor.

I found that this code does the trick:

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['field_id_4']) {
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['field_id_4']);
}        
CKEDITOR.replace('field_id_4',{
    allowedContent: 
        'img[!src,alt,width,height]{float};' + 
        'h1 h2 div'
    });
```

But only when the top condition is there.

Now I see though, that the CKeditor is duplicated...

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`editor.destroy()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy) instead of [`CKEDITOR.remove`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-remove) which is a private method.

Something like:

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['field_id_4']) {
    CKEDITOR.instances['field_id_4'].destroy();
}        
CKEDITOR.replace('field_id_4',{
    allowedContent: 
        'img[!src,alt,width,height]{float};' + 
        'h1 h2 div'
});
```